# Textboxes exceed width of <div> container

Tags: html, css

I have a few textboxes set to `width: 100%` inside a `<div>` with the `width` of `350px`, they go outside of the div on the right side, and I don't understand, why?

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1p2maw0/)

Also, code here (same as fiddle):

```
<body>       
    <div class="centerthis">
    <form method="post" action="~/AJAXcalls/InsWrkOAJAX.cshtml">
        <div class="insertWorkoutFormHolder">
            <label class="radioLabel" for="typ4">Primary</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Type" id="typ4" value="4" class="radioSelect"><br />
            <label class="radioLabel" for="typ5">Secondary</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Type" id="typ5" value="5" class="radioSelect" /><br />
            <label class="radioLabel" for="typ6">Assistance</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Type" id="typ6" value="6" class="radioSelect" /><br />
            <br>
            <div class="hideThis">
                <label class="radioLabel" for="hej1">Squat</label>
                <input class="radioSelect" type="radio" name="Exercise" id="hej1" value="1" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="hideThis">
                <label class="radioLabel" for="hej2">Benchpress</label>
                <input class="radioSelect" type="radio" name="Exercise" id="hej2" value="2" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="hideThis">
                <label class="radioLabel" for="hej3">Deadlift</label>
                <input class="radioSelect" type="radio" name="Exercise" id="hej3" value="3" />
            </div>
            <br />

            <div>
                <input id="dailyPR" placeholder="Daily Max..." name="dailyPR" type="text" size="50" value="" class="hideThis insertWorkoutBoxes" />
            </div>
            <!-- Textbox for amount of weight. -->
            <div>
                <input placeholder="Weight..." name="Kg" type="text" size="50" value="" class="insertWorkoutBoxes" />
            </div>
            <!-- Textbox for number of sets. -->
            <div>
                <input placeholder="Number of sets..." name="Sett" type="number" size="50" value="" class="insertWorkoutBoxes" />
            </div>
            <!-- Textbox for number of reps. -->
            <div>
                <input placeholder="Number of reps..." name="Rep" type="number" size="50" value="" class="insertWorkoutBoxes" />
            </div>
            <!-- Textbox for date of workout. -->
            <input placeholder="" type="text" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off"
                   class="datepicker workoutVariSelect capitalFirst" name="Date" value="" readonly="readonly" />
            <div>
                <!-- Form submit button. -->
                <br /><a class="AddBtn">Add</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```css
.AddBtn {
    padding: 10px 70px 10px 70px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.centerthis {
    text-align:center;
}
.radioSelect {
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 115px 0px 0px;
}
.radioLabel {
     float:left;
     margin-left: 80px;
}
.insertWorkoutFormHolder {
    width: 350px;
    margin:auto;
}
.workoutVariSelect {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 11px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
    font-family: Verdana;   
    font-weight: 500;
    background: #fff center right 10px no-repeat url('Images/pil.jpg'); 
    background-size: 12px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.insertWorkoutBoxes {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    padding: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some default paddings and borders set on most of the form element such as `<input type="text">`. You can apply `box-sizing: border-box` along with the `width: 100%`, so that `padding` and `border` will be part of total `width`.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid aqua;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.border-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="border-box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the padding in the input field which is not considered in width 100%. You should use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: please check existing answers before submitting yours